# MVC DisplayFor templates seem to quit working if the same model is reused within the template

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a really strange situation.  I have a single Model, and two templates that are both strong-typed on the type of this model.  The templates are nested, or in other words, I use DisplayFor on the second Template from within the first template.  If I use the model associated with the first template, in the DisplayFor call for the second template, the second template does not render.  If I use another instance of the same model type, everything works fine.  It seems like there is some sort of cycle checking on the models associated with nested templates.

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public MyModel Copy
    {
        get { return (MyModel) this.MemberwiseClone(); }
    }

    public MyModel MySelf
    {
        get { return this; }
    }
}
```

DisplayTemplate1:

```
@model TestNestedTemplateSameReference.Models.MyModel

<div>Model1</div>
<div>@Model.Value</div>
<div>@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x, "ModelTemplate2")</div>
```

DisplayTemplate2:

```
@model TestNestedTemplateSameReference.Models.MyModel

<div>Model2</div>
<div>@Model.Value</div>
```

Interestingly if instead of calling

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x, "ModelTemplate2")
```

I call it with the Copy property

```
<div>@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.Copy, "ModelTemplate2")</div>
```

everything works fine as the actual instance of the MyModel class is different.

Does anyone know why this is done.  Is there a viable workaround.  It seems like this is a perfectly legitimate usage which shouldnot cause a stack overflow, or any similar issues.  I could see how this could be used to protect against cycles for DisplayFor call without template name, but if I specify the template name seems like it should work fine.

It seems like it would be dangerous to bind the same model to multiple EditFor templates, but DisplayFor seems safe.

I can of course create a separate model for nesting level, but that is creating redundand class.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If what you were trying to do worked, it would result in a stack overflow as object after object was created via the Copy method.  Each object would in turn create a new copy of itself, and you would quickly either run out of memory or run out of stack.

The default template executes this method before showing a property

```
bool ShouldShow(ModelMetadata metadata) {
    return metadata.ShowForEdit
        && metadata.ModelType != typeof(System.Data.EntityState)
        && !metadata.IsComplexType
        && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(metadata);
}
```

My guess is that it's tripping either IsComplexType or TemplateInfo.Visited.

There's more info on this here:

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html

Comment: Why would it do that?  I don't have an infinite nesting loop.  Nesting of templates stops after two.  In fact if this behavior is due to protections against infinite nesting, it seems like the test should be on the template name, or template instance as opposed to the model.  In fact using .Copy property works just fine.

Comment: Mystere Man, do you know if the ShouldShow behavior can be overwritten or if there are any extension points I could use to change the behavior?

Comment: @EugeneTsimberg - Yes, you can override it with a new Object template.  If you download the source for the MVC3 Futures, it includes the default templates used internally.  If you place the Ojbect.ascx in ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates then modify it, it will use that instead.